# Regression scoring

Tags: multiple-regression

When evaluating a multiple regression usually I look at mean absolute/squared error, aic/bic, and adjusted rsquared, but very rarely does the information coefficient (correlation between actual and predicted values) ever get quoted.

Is there a flaw in this statistic that I haven't thought of?

Is there any reason why you shouldn't try to optimise this score during feature selection as opposed to the usual candidates (MAE or adjusted rsquared)?

Comment: what is the goal of information coefficient ?

Comment: To show the strength of a linear relationship between the two sets of values whilst being comparable to other regressions with varying types and numbers of features since it is standardised between 1 and -1.

Comment: I have seen this score quoted in financial prediction literature a few times.